# Is there a way to import every submodule using --hidden-import in pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

We are using Pyinstaller and we have a module that has several hidden "submodules".
So, currently, we need to use --hiden-import module.submodule1 --hiden-import module.submodule2 and so on.

I've tried --hiden-import module, but it didn't work.

Is there a way to import all the submodules in a single statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--collect-all` flag, however this will also include any other files located in the package such as metadata files, icons, datasets or anything else contained in the package.

```
--collect-all modulename
```

Answer (score -1):

There is now an option `--collect-submodules` that does just that e.g. in your case `--collect-submodules module`